# Write to Serial Port, Pipe Output to a File

Tags: unix, command-line, serial-port

I'm trying to communicate with a device over a serial port, and pipe its output to a file. I've managed to use the screen program to communicate with the device, but I'm not sure how to pipe the data I receive to a file.

For example, right now can start the screen program with: `sudo screen /dev/ttyACM0`. Then I can send the command DATA to the device, and the data I want gets printed to my console. Now I want to send that data to a file.

stty doesn't seem to be working for me due to some permission error. Using sudo didn't help.

Does anyone have ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried using [`tee`](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/)? `screen` can also output to a file using [ctrl-a, h](http://www.phacks.net/how-to-use-gnu-screen/).

Comment: The `tee` command only seems to work with commands that have an output. `screen` doesn't seem to have an output for `tee` to grab, at least in my testing. The screen capture worked, but only for what was literally on my screen. Nothing previously written during my session was recorded. The output from my device is thousands of lines at a time, which no monitor I own can display.